# Hierarchy is not being created for my target variation label

Tags: 2013, language, variations

I am currently having a hard time setting up variations in Sharepoint 2013. First, I create my source Label, based on English language. Then I go into the central admin and run the "Variations Create Hierarchies Job Definition". Everything works fine, when I look at the variation labels list, I see "Yes" under "Hierarchy is created".

Then I create a second label, fr, which is based on French language. All the options are the basic ones. Then I do the same thing, run the job, and nothing happens.  The job runs successfully, but the hierarchy for fr is never created.

Anyone has an idea of what could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run additional timer jobs. For the root variation (in your case english), running the Variations Create Hierarchies Job Definition is sufficient to create the hierarchy. For all additional variation labels you need to start additional timer jobs. In central administration you should see these 4 timer jobs related to variations (per web application): `Variations Create Hierarchies Job Definition`, `Variations Propagate List Items Job Definition`, `Variations Propagate Page Job Definition` and `Variations Propagate Site and Lists Timer Job`. After creating the second label and clicking the "Create Hierarchies" link you must start additional timer jobs. I can't test it right now, but I am fairly sure you need to start the `Variations Propagate Sites and Lists Timer Job`. Make sure that the timer jobs actually finish by checking the job's history.

However, with the default settings all of your variations related timer jobs should run (at least) once an hour. Just waiting for an hour should get you there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the SharePoint timer service is running under windows services

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE, Awadi! Your answer is a general advice, which is valid to almost half the questions here. Do you have any specific advice or example where you solved this issue starting the timer service?